# left icon not visible

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

A have an `Activity` (minSDK for my app = 14) to which the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog` Theme is applied. I need to set an icon, so I used

```
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    this.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
            R.drawable.share);
```

I guess the icon is set (because the title moved to the right) but for some reason it is not visible as if it was transparent:

[image]

I can't find any logical explanation for this behavior. Any ideas?

P.S. no, my drawable is not the same color as the window's background

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken then you have to set your icon resource on custom `Dialog` after calling `show` on it.

```
dialog.show();
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.share);
```

Its still a mystery why does it work and not the other way :)

Comment: "A have an Activity">>>> this is not a dialog but a dialog-themed Activity

Comment: well thanks for your responses, I got tired of that and just used a normal Dialog. Now it works fine. Must be some kind of bug with a dialog-themed Activity

Comment: in your dialog activity, you were actually supposed to call **setFeatureDrawableResource** after **setContentView**

Answer (score 0):

it is order:

1 ) `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);`

2) `this.setContentView(R.layout.xxx);`

if is Dialog (`dialog.show();`)

3) `this.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.share);`